# Is every unambiguous grammar regular?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, proof-techniques, ambiguity

While searching for an answer to this question I found out that there is an unambiguous grammar for every regular language.
But is there a regular language for every unambiguous grammar? How can I prove that this is/isn't true?

Comment: Have you tried finding an unambiguous grammar for $a^nb^n$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following grammar is unambiguous yet generates a non-regular language:
$$ S \to aSb \mid \epsilon $$

Comment: As a side note, this works for every $a,b \in \Sigma$ where $a \neq b$. A very notable example would be the language of matched parenthesis $(^n)^n$.

Comment: It's been some time since my theory courses. Is this the trivial PDA?

Comment: This is a context-free grammar, not a push down automaton.